# Inter-app communication within application server without MQ

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-integration

I'm looking at exposing separate services inside an application server, and all services need to authenticate with the same API key.

Rather than each request authenticating with the DB individually, I was hoping I could write the authentication service and configuration once, do some caching of the available API keys, and expose that auth service to the other services on the app server (TC, Glassfish, etc).  I don't think HTTP loopback is a good choice, so I was looking at Spring Integration, JavaEE, RMI, etc.

There's lots of info available, but it's still not clear to me if this is something that Spring Integration can support after reading through some documentation and projects.  It looks like Spring makes the assumption you're in-app, or MQ based (external MQ or embedded MQ.) I'm also not sure if this is something inherently available in EJB implementations with Jboss or Glassfish...It seems like it might be though.

While MQ's seem possible, they seem like overkill for what my purpose is. I really just need to pass a bean to my authentication service on the same box, and respond with a bean/boolean on whether the key was approved or not.

Anyone have some guidance on accomplishing something like this? (or maybe why I'm making the wrong decision?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via plain [PCT/IP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html) or [RMI](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/rmi.html).

But I don't see problem to follow with [Micro Service Architecture](http://yobriefca.se/blog/2013/04/29/micro-service-architecture/) principles and use the [Spring Integration REST ability](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html)

Any networks access you always can restrict via firewalls and HTTP-proxies.